# Is the word about in this sentence being used as a noun?

Tags: grammaticality

I introduced myself in my new job today and I was told to use this phrase to wrap up my presentation "That about covers who I am" What I can understand from this phrase is the "about" part is being used as a noun which is a function I could not find in any dictionary, Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not being used as a noun, but as an adverb.

Although your parsing of the sentence is not correct, it does make grammatical sense.  A noun could fit into that structure.  Consider:

*That **summary** covers who I am*

This still isn't especially idiomatic, but it's definitely syntactically valid.

What's actually going on in this sentence is that *about* is modifying the verb *covers*.  Your introduction *about covers*.

Again, if we swap *about* with a word that's more obviously an adverb, the structure might become clearer:

*That almost covers who I am*

*That practically covers who I am*

*That mostly covers who I am*

These other sentences have more or less the same meaning as the original.

Comment: I'd just add for clarity, the subject of the sentence is "that", which is being used as a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

No, **about** is not a noun here, and *about* cannot be used as a noun.  *About* is being used as an adverb here, to describe how "covers" is being done.

The meaning here is "That *roughly* or *approximately* covers who I am."  This is essentially [definition 1a at Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about):

> 1 a : reasonably close to

Comment: I didn't know about that meaning, thank you!

Comment: I would say that 'about' used like that is mainly US dialectical (sometimes seen as _'bout_ in some rural or regional speech). Brits might say 'just about'.

Comment: Most Linux programs have an **About** option accessible from a drop-down menu option alongside things like **Help** and **Check for updates**. As the name implies, the **About** option shows things like version number, copyright notices, etc. But I'd be happy to see just the label itself used as a (capitalised) noun: *"This app's About lists all the developers who have ever worked on it!"* As is usually the case with English, just about any word can be forced into just about any Part of Speech!